# Iterating over array of objects in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, object, iteration

I'm working with Angular (so typescript) on a projet.
I try to iterate over an object

---

I build an object in a service like so :

```
class Point {
  id: number;
  name: string; 

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

I fill an array with theses points that i get from a database

```
private pointList: Point[] = [];
```

I make a fonction to get back theses points in other 'components' in angular

```
getPointsList() {
    return this.pointList;
  }
```

> all of this is done in a points.service.ts
>
> ---

So the problem is,

In an other component i load those points in a local variable

```ts
pointList = this.pointsService.getPointsList();
```

en then i try to iterate over them like so :

```
console.log(this.pointList); // first consoleLog
for (const point of this.pointList) {
      console.log(point); // second consoleLog
      console.log(point.id); // third consoleLog
}
```

> all of this is done in an other file, in a component, map.ts
>
> ---

the results of the console.log are :

1. an array containing my objects like : [{id: 1    name: 'test'    }    {    id: 2    name: 'test2'    }] *an that's normal i think*
2. nothing
3. nothing

---

so i think that it don't event enter the for loop but i don't see why.

i also tried

- to `console.log(this.pointList[0])` but it return an undefine
- `this.pointList.forEach(point => {console.log(point)});`but it
  didn't print anything

---

here is my 'real' code and what it show in the console :

[image]
[image]

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

**thanks**

Comment: If you replace your first log statement with `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.pointList));`, what do you get?

Comment: sorry i didn't see, i get an empty array : []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably try to see the values before the array has been populated. It appears to work for

```
console.log(this.pointList);
```

but this is because the array shown in the console window is dynamic: it displays the values as they are when you expand the array in the console window, not as they were when the `console.log` statement was executed.

To see the array as it is when the `console.log` statement is executed, use the following statement:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.pointList));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for (const point of this.pointList) {` instead.

For in iterate on all keys of object include his prototype, so in you want to use it you have to remember about `if (this.pointList.hasOwnProperty(point) {`. For of is kind of shortcut for that.

Also you can use `this.pointList.forEach(point => {...`. Personally it's my favourite method because you can join it with `.map`, `.filter`, or `.find` methods

Comment: i just tried and it didn't change anything sadly
and

this.pointList.forEach(point => {console.log(point)}); 

don't print anything

Comment: yes that work, console.log(typeof this.pointList) return a type of array and the list of objects in it, and the console.log(this.pointList) show the list in the console

Comment: so `console.log(this.pointList)` prints `[{id: 1 name: 'test' } { id: 2 name: 'test2' }]`, but `point => {console.log(point)}` print `undefined`?

Comment: i added 2 screen of what i get, but point => {console.log(point)} dont print a line in the console

Comment: weird, try `Array.from(this.pointList).forEach(point => console.log(point);`